# Out-of-sync AUTO_INCREMENT values in development_structure.sql from Rails/MySQL creates diff noise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

Our team is developing a Rails app on MySQL and using `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` per [The Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps).

Naturally, our `AUTO_INCREMENT` values in `development_structure.sql` get out-of-sync as we develop in parallel. We know that having different values in our databases for `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not a technical problem. However, it creates a lot of `diff` noise when we `diff` before checking-in. On more than one occasion we have broken our build because one of us missed an important change in `development_structure.sql` that was disguised by all the noise.

Any suggestions on how to eliminate this `diff` noise so our eyes can focus on important changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a dumb question?

Comment: What does the actual diff look like? Your diff tool may need upgrading.

Comment: The diff was fine. It showed that each developer's development MySQL database had a different AUTO_INCREMENT value for each table, which naturally occurs when developers are creating records on their own machines.

Comment: Definitely not a dumb question!  I think it's just not that common to use `schema_format = :sql`. Thanks for the hint on how to proceed, this was bothering me too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variant of the accepted answer is to include the following in a .rake file in lib/tasks:

```
Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].enhance do
  path = Rails.root.join('db', 'structure.sql')
  File.write path, File.read(path).gsub(/ AUTO_INCREMENT=\d*/, '')
end
```

This has the advantage of making the change in behavior appear more intentional (as suggested by:  http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/52300664342/how-to-extend-an-existing-rake-task), esp. if put into a descriptively named file (e.g. 'skip_auto_increment.rake').

Answer (score 13):

@Ian, thank you very much for the hint. But on Rails 3.2 now it is much simpler. There is no need to invoke tasks since it leads to stack level too deep error and there is no need to override the task description. So my code is like that:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :structure do
    task :dump do
      path = Rails.root.join('db', 'structure.sql')
      File.write path, File.read(path).gsub(/ AUTO_INCREMENT=\d*/, '')
    end
  end
end
```

Works both for `db:migrate` and `db:structure:dump`.

Comment: This does not work under Ruby 1.9.2 "undefined method `write' for File:Class"

Comment: This method is available under 1.9.3

Comment: Answering my own question: lib/tasks/db.rake.

Answer (score 5):

At [Razoo](http://www.razoo.com/), we ended up overriding db:migrate

```
task :migrate do
  Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
  Rake::Task['db:structure:dump'].invoke
end
```

and then db:structure:dump

```
namespace :structure do
  desc "Dump the database structure to a SQL file"
    task :dump do
      Rake::Task['db:structure:dump'].invoke
      # open up the development_structure.sql file and gsub AUTO_INCREMENT=\d* with AUTO_INCREMENT
    end
  end
end
```